# Rails 3.1 ActionMailer: "DEPRECATION WARNING: charset() is deprecated"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer

re: this code in Rails' ActionMailer...

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b5f9a9fce316e96ffb9ab3a69e9311f8b1e56fde#actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb-P14

the above link includes a code comment about a warning produced by ActionMailer:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: charset() is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
```

is there any known solution to this?

**UPDATE**

You may hate it, but to get on with my day, I just stuck this in my mailer class until I could upgrade to rails 3.2:

```
def charset
  @charset
end
```

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory solution to this problem? I'm having it with rails 3.1.8 and:

    actionmailer (3.1.8)
      actionpack (= 3.1.8)
      mail (~> 2.3.3)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's still an issue? The charset method in the Mail gem does't have anything about a deprecation warning. I wonder if that was for a specific version of the mail gem and it has since been changed.

https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/message.rb#L1423

Comment: so, i'm working on a Rails 3.1.4 app which depends on Mail ~2.3.0. up to Mail 2.3.3 i still get this noisy warning.